# Real analysis problem on Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve this problem in my textbook and I am completely lost or do not know how to begin this problem:

**Problem:** Denote $H^n(A)$ as the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $H^n([-N,N]^n)<+\infty$ for any square cube $[-N,N]^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $N\in \mathbb{N}$

Can anyone give me some hints to how I would try and approach this problem, I am not sure what to let the length of one cube to be, I am imagining the length can be something like $\frac{\delta}{ 2\sqrt{n}}$, but I am not entirely sure where to go from here if the length is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track.

Without knowing your textbook, I'll cite Folland

**Definition**

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space, $p\geq 0$, and $\delta>0$. For $A\subset X$,

\begin{equation}
H_{p,\delta} 
=
\inf
\left\{
\sum_1^\infty
(\text{diam }B_j)^p
:
A
\subset
\bigcup_1^\infty
B_j
\
\text{and}
\
\text{diam }B_j
\leq \delta 
\right\}
\end{equation}

The limit of $H_{p,\delta}(A)$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ is the $p$ dimensional Hausdorff measure of $A$, denoted $H_p(A)$.

**Some observations**

1. Since $H_{p,\delta}$ is defined as an infimum, we only need a single covering for each $\delta$. We just need a good choice so that the limit is finite
2. The diameter of $[-N,N]^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $2N\sqrt{n}$

If $\delta < 2N\sqrt{n}$ we can cover the cube $[-N,N]^n$ with a union of smaller cubes (of diameter $\delta$), all translates of
$\left[-\frac{\delta}{2\sqrt{n}},\frac{\delta}{2\sqrt{n}}\right]^n$.

Let $J_\delta$ be the smallest integer such that $\frac{\delta}{2\sqrt{n}} J_{\delta} \geq N$, i.e.

\begin{equation}
J_{\delta}
=
\left\lceil \frac{2N\sqrt{n}}{\delta}  \right\rceil
\end{equation}

There are $J_\delta^n$ cubes in the covering, so

\begin{align}
H_{n,\delta}
&\leq 
(\text{number of the cubes})(\text{diameter of each cube})^n\\
&=
(J_\delta^n) \delta \\
&\leq
\left(\frac{2N\sqrt{n}}{\delta}+1 \right)^n \delta^n \\
&=
\left(2N\sqrt{n}+\delta \right)^n  \\
\end{align}

The limit of this expression as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ is $(2N\sqrt{n})^n$, which is finite, and $H_n$ must be less than this value.

Comment: Oh my this helped me, thanks !